# Задача Обратные числа C++

Tags: c++, математика, теория-чисел

**Обратное число**

В этой задаче нужно ответить на ***1≤t≤105***
запросов. Каждый запрос состоит из двух целых чисел ***2≤p≤109*** и ***0<a<p***, число p является простым. На каждый запрос нужно вывести в отдельной строке целое число ***0<b<p*** такое, что ***(a⋅b−1) ⋮ p***.

**Входные данные:**

В первой строке дано целое число ***t***   — количество запросов.
В следующих t строках даны по два числа ***pi*** и ***ai***, ***i=1,…,t***

**Выходные данные:**
Выведите ***t***
целых чисел (каждое число в отдельной строке) — ответы на запросы.

## Примеры:

**Ввод**

```
4

5 1

5 2

5 3

5 4
```

Вывод

```
1
3
2
4
```

`cpp`

```
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;
int pow_plus(int a, int b){
    int z = pow(b, a - 2);
    return z % a;
}

int main()
{
    int n;
    int a,b;
    cin >> n;
    int mas[n];
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        cin >> a;
        cin >> b;
        mas[i] = pow_plus(a,b);
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){

        cout << mas[i];
        if(i + 1 != n){
            cout <<'\n';
        }
    }



    setlocale(LC_ALL, "rus");
    return 0;

}
```

Вердикт: Неверный ответ, почему не работает?

Comment: `int z = pow(b, a - 2);` - переполнение.

Comment: В С++  это `cin >> n;   int mas[n];`  не работает. `n` должна быть константой. Если размер массива хочется вводить, то используйте std::vector. Ну или простой динамический массив.

Comment: @Vladimir В данном случае проблема не в этом (обычно во всех проверялках GCC, а у него это работает).

Comment: Быстрое возведение в степень + взятие остатка помогут. И давайте в таких случаях URL проверяющей системы! P.S. А вы хоть знаете, почему решение именно такое?

Answer (score 4):

В комментарий не лезет...

Вот, как-то набрасывал для себя такую функцию - возведения в степень по модулю...

```
//// Быстрое возведение в степень по модулю p
template<typename T, typename U, typename P,
         typename = std::enable_if_t<std::is_integral<T>::value &&
                                     std::is_unsigned<P>::value &&
                                     std::is_unsigned<U>::value>
        >
T iqpow(T x, U e, P p)
{
    T res = static_cast<T>(1);
    x %= p;
    for(;e;e>>=1)
    {
        if (e&1) res = (res*x)%p;
        x = (x*x)%p;
    }
    return res;
}
```